# Edit the VPC Deafult Security group with CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-vpc

How can I edit the VPC default security (or any other already existing security group)? My objective is to make the default security group closed i.e with no ingress or egress rules.

Comment: Please share some progress of what you have tried so far and the issues you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

For AWS **Python CDK**, check out the documentation here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_ec2/CfnSecurityGroupEgress.html

Using AWS **boto3 SDK**, you could do it in the following ways.
Here, you have to provide here the **default security group** of your VPC only.

```
import logging
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import json

AWS_REGION = 'us-east-1'

logger = logging.getLogger()
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s')

vpc_client = boto3.client("ec2", region_name=AWS_REGION)


def delete_ingress_rule(security_group_id, ip_permissions):
    # Deletes a security group ingress rule.
    try:
        response = vpc_client.revoke_security_group_ingress(
            GroupId=security_group_id,
            IpPermissions=ip_permissions)

    except ClientError as e:
        logger.exception('Could not delete ingress security group rule.', e)
    else:
        return response


def delete_egress_rule(security_group_id, ip_permissions):
    # Deletes a security group egress rule.
    try:
        response = vpc_client.revoke_security_group_egress(
            GroupId=security_group_id,
            IpPermissions=ip_permissions)

    except ClientError as e:
        logger.exception('Could not delete egress security group rule.', e)
    else:
        return response


if __name__ == '__main__':

    SECURITY_GROUP_ID = "sg-099a2f114393e9258"
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

    sg = ec2.SecurityGroup(SECURITY_GROUP_ID)

    if sg.ip_permissions:
        logger.info(f'Found {len(sg.ip_permissions)} ingress ip_permissions for security group {SECURITY_GROUP_ID}.')
        logger.info(f'Removing all ip_permissions_egress of security group {SECURITY_GROUP_ID}')
        rule = delete_ingress_rule(SECURITY_GROUP_ID, sg.ip_permissions)
        logger.info(
            f'{SECURITY_GROUP_ID} Security group ip_permissions rule(s) deleted: \n{json.dumps(rule, indent=4)}'
        )
    else:
        logger.info(
            f'Found {len(sg.ip_permissions)} ingress ip_permissions for security group {SECURITY_GROUP_ID}.')
    if sg.ip_permissions_egress:
        logger.info(
            f'Found {len(sg.ip_permissions_egress)} egress ip_permissions for security group {SECURITY_GROUP_ID}.')
        logger.info(f'Removing all ip_permissions_egress of security group {SECURITY_GROUP_ID}')
        rule = delete_egress_rule(SECURITY_GROUP_ID, sg.ip_permissions_egress)
        logger.info(
            f'{SECURITY_GROUP_ID} Security group ip_permissions_egress rule(s) deleted: \n{json.dumps(rule, indent=4)}'
        )
    else:
        logger.info(
            f'Found {len(sg.ip_permissions_egress)} egress ip_permissions for security group {SECURITY_GROUP_ID}.')
```

**Output:**

```
2022-10-24 17:44:25,061: INFO: Found credentials in shared credentials file: ~/.aws/credentials
2022-10-24 17:44:26,393: INFO: Found 2 ingress ip_permissions for security group sg-099a2f114393e9258.
2022-10-24 17:44:26,393: INFO: Removing all ip_permissions_egress of security group sg-099a2f114393e9258
2022-10-24 17:44:27,665: INFO: sg-099a2f114393e9258 Security group ip_permissions rule(s) deleted: 
{
    "Return": true,
    "ResponseMetadata": {
        "RequestId": "7b54821b-25e4-49ba-b67b-054003125a95",
        "HTTPStatusCode": 200,
        "HTTPHeaders": {
            "x-amzn-requestid": "7b54821b-25e4-49ba-b67b-054003125a95",
            "cache-control": "no-cache, no-store",
            "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
            "content-type": "text/xml;charset=UTF-8",
            "content-length": "253",
            "date": "Mon, 24 Oct 2022 12:14:26 GMT",
            "server": "AmazonEC2"
        },
        "RetryAttempts": 0
    }
}
2022-10-24 17:44:27,665: INFO: Found 2 egress ip_permissions for security group sg-099a2f114393e9258.
2022-10-24 17:44:27,665: INFO: Removing all ip_permissions_egress of security group sg-099a2f114393e9258
2022-10-24 17:44:28,177: INFO: sg-099a2f114393e9258 Security group ip_permissions_egress rule(s) deleted: 
{
    "Return": true,
    "ResponseMetadata": {
        "RequestId": "8bd10e3d-ed59-42f9-8f79-ba83f5985229",
        "HTTPStatusCode": 200,
        "HTTPHeaders": {
            "x-amzn-requestid": "8bd10e3d-ed59-42f9-8f79-ba83f5985229",
            "cache-control": "no-cache, no-store",
            "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
            "content-type": "text/xml;charset=UTF-8",
            "content-length": "251",
            "date": "Mon, 24 Oct 2022 12:14:27 GMT",
            "server": "AmazonEC2"
        },
        "RetryAttempts": 0
    }
}
```

If you want to remove all ingress and egress rules for **default VPC**, you could go with the following VPC_ID based approach.

```
import boto3

VPC_ID = "vpc-0b27a2237825184ae"

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
vpc = ec2.Vpc(VPC_ID)

try:
    vpc_security_group_default_iterator = vpc.security_groups.filter(
        # GroupIds=['string'], # The IDs of the security groups. Required for security groups in a non-default VPC.
        GroupNames=['default']
    )
    for vpc_security_group_default_it in vpc_security_group_default_iterator:
        print(vpc_security_group_default_it)
        try:
            vpc_security_group_default_it.revoke_ingress(IpPermissions=vpc_security_group_default_it.ip_permissions)
            vpc_security_group_default_it.revoke_egress(
                IpPermissions=vpc_security_group_default_it.ip_permissions_egress)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

But in the case of **non-default VPC**, boto3 documentation says to use the **group-name** filter to describe security groups by name, not enough documentation is available on this.

Via **AWS Console**, follow this:

- Head to the VPC Security Groups https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/home?region=us-east-1#SecurityGroups
- Select your VPC default security group or either just filter with your VPC ID, and select the security group with name default,
- Edit inbound and outbound rules and delete all of the rules there.

The same you could do with the terraform and CLI.

Comment: The question is about CDK, though.

Comment: The updated answer uses the SDK, not CDK.